# Как тестировать ошибки компиляции?

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, шаблоны-с++, компиляция, тестирование

Возможно ли как-то тестировать ошибки компиляции похожим образом, как делают юнит-тесты для ошибок рантайма? Есть ли библиотеки для этого?

Например, есть шаблонная функция, которая должна компилироваться для одного аргумента, но не компилироваться для другого. Как написать `ASSERT`, который покажет, что произошла ошибка компиляции и при этом не остановит компиляцию и работу тестов?

```
struct S {
    int x;
} s1;

int s2;

template <class T>
void foo_for_test(T t) {
    t.x;
}

int main() {
    /* COMPILE_ASSERT_TRUE  */ foo_for_test(s1);
    /* COMPILE_ASSERT_FALSE */ foo_for_test(s2);
}
```

Comment: Для этого следует написать функцию, компилирующую эту функцию и тестировать ее.

Comment: @user7860670 типа функции, которая делает системный вызов компилятора и передаёт ему необходимый код, а дальше смотрит код возврата этого вызова?

Comment: Ну как-то так. И еще проверят вывод компилятора.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки компиляции можно обработать только на уровне системы сборки, но не изнутри компилируемого кода. Поэтому, например, в CMake есть функция [try_compile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html#try-compiling-source-files), которая позволяет проверить компилируется ли конкретный файл, с заданным набором опций компилятора, и использовать знание об успехе или провале в дальнейшем процессе сборки. Обычно, эта функция используется для проверки возможностей компилятора, и установленных библиотек, но можно и для тестирования ошибок компиляции.

Предпочтительнее писать код так, чтобы не возникало необходимости в таких проверках.
Например, можно перенести ошибку на уровень ошибки подстановки параметров шаблона, тогда это будет не ошибкой компиляции, а ошибкой подстановки, которую можно диагностировать. С использованием С++20 это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
template <class T>
   requires  requires (T t){ t.x; } // требования к T
void foo_for_test(T t) {
    t.x;
}
```

Проверка:

```
template <typename ... Args >
constexpr bool foo_for_test_callable 
    = requires { foo_for_test( std::declval<Args>()...); }
    ;

static_assert( foo_for_test_callable<decltype(s1)> == true );
static_assert( foo_for_test_callable<decltype(s2)> == false );
```

Для более ранних версий C++ это будет выглядеть гораздо многословнее, с использованием std::enabled_if и SFINAE. Но в любом случае, проверка - это не проверка  компилируемости функции, а проверка возможности подстановки аргументов.

Comment: Абзацы, посвященные концептам вообще ни к месту. Их использование никак не снимает необходимость потенциально тестировать ошибки компиляции.