# Как протестировать функцию, которая не должна компилироваться?

Tags: c++

Часто в коде бывает случай, когда нужно ограничить что-то на этапе компиляции, например, сделать так, чтобы функция не могла принимать любой тип кроме `int`

```
template<class Ty>
void foo(const Ty& value) {
  static_assert(!is_same_v<Ty, int>, "");
  // do_something();
}
```

Но можно ли написать какой-то тест, который будет проверять, что описанный выше функционал присутствует в функции и находится в рабочем состоянии?

```
TEST(FooTest, CompilationErrorWIthInt){
  // Возможно как-то протестировать то, что при 
  foo(static_cast<int>(1));
  // будет ошибка компиляции?
}

TEST(FooTest, GoodCompilation){
  foo(static_cast<char>(1));
  foo(static_cast<double>(1));
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1403927/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1404006#1404006

Comment: Там про структуры говорится, а как проверить структуры я знаю. У меня не получается проверить функции, внутри которых есть static_assert.

Comment: Нет, там говорится про ошибки компиляции вообще и приведен пример с проверкой функции. Видимо вы даже не удосужились прочитать дубликат.

Answer (score 1):

Для перегрузки шаблонных функций и для специализации классов используются SFINAE и концепты. `static_assert` же предназначен исключительно для генерации ошибки в случае, когда в процессе инстанцирования куска кода, в которой вставлен `static_assert`, его аргументом окажется `false`. Не важно, по каким причинам будет инстацирован этот  кусок кода, ошибка компиляции возникнет, даже если результат инстанцирования используется только при проверке SFINAE или концепта. А SFINAE  и концепты оценивают только сигнатуру, тело шаблона инстанцируется только в случае, если это нужно для вывода типа.

Пример:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
template<class... > using void_t = void;

template<class T, class = void>
struct test: std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct test<T, void_t<decltype(T::foo())>>: std::true_type{};

template<class T>
struct Ok{
    // Тип возвращаемого значения определен явно в сигнатуре
    static T foo(){
       static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>{}, "Ok<T>: T is not an integer");
       return T{};
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Err{
    // Тип возвращаемого значения выводится в результате инстанцирования тела функции
    static auto foo(){
       static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>{}, "Err<T>: T is not an integer");
       return T{};
    }
};

static_assert(test<Ok<char>>{}, "Ok<char> test"); // Ok

static_assert(test<Err<char>>{}, "Err<char> test"); // static assertion failed: Err<T>: T is not an integer
// При этом нет ошибки "Err<char> test"

// static_assert(!test<Err<char>>{}, "!test<Err<char>>{}")  - а тут была бы ошибка в двух static_assert
```

Т.е. вместо static_assert вы должны были написать следующее:

```cpp
template<class Ty, std::enable_if_t<!is_same_v<Ty, int>, bool> = true>
void foo(const Ty& value) {
  // do_something();
}
```

Или использовать концепты.